# django-tinymce doesn't show up in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce

I can't get the django-tinymce module gui to show up in the admin of my django project.

Here's `settings.py` (tinymce settings are at the end):

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'notices.apps.NoticesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'imagekit',
    'leaflet',
    'nested_admin',
    'tinymce'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'orag.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'orag.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'xxxxxx',
        'NAME': 'xxxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },

    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend"
# EMAIL_FILE_PATH = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('sent_emails'))

# print(BASE_DIR)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

# LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
#     'DEFAULT_CENTER': (47.019214, 5.855572),
#     'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 5,
#     'MAX_ZOOM': 20,
#     'MIN_ZOOM':3,
#     'SCALE': 'both',
#     'ATTRIBUTION_PREFIX': 'OrAG'
# }

TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + 'tinymce/tinymce.min.js'

TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT + 'tinymce'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "height": "320px",
    "width": "960px",
    "menubar": "file edit view insert format tools table help",
    "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code "
    "fullscreen insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount spellchecker",
    "toolbar": "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft "
    "aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor "
    "backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | "
    "fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample | "
    "a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment code",
    "custom_undo_redo_levels": 10,
    "language": "es_ES",  # To force a specific language instead of the Django current language.
}

TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('notices/', include('notices.urls')),
    path('_nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And an extract of `admin.py` (imports and the only model class that will be updated through the admin. I skipped the whole file with Inlines and so on, let me know if it's needed):

```
class ObjetArchiAdmin(GeoModelAdminMixin, nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE()}
        }
    list_display = ('titre', 'users', 'date', 'id')
    fieldsets = (
        ('État-Civil', {
            'fields': (('titre', 'date', 'users'), 'resume')
        }),
        ('Provenance et attribution', {
            'fields': ('point', ('prov_pays', 'prov_region'), ('prov_departement', 'prov_ville'), 'lieu_dit',  'attribution')
        }),
        ('Conservation', {
            'fields': (('cons_pays', 'cons_region'), ('cons_departement', 'cons_ville'),('cons_depot', 'cons_no_inventaire'), 'cons_localisation')
        }),
        ('Description', {
            'fields': ('description', 'contexte', 'observations_comp', ('materiau', 'stuc', 'polychromie'), 'hauteur_debut')
        }),
        ('Analyse et Datation', {
            'fields': ('analyse', 'inedit', 'ref_biblio', 'ref_biblio_2', ('date_chrono_debut', 'date_chrono_fin'), ('citeantique', 'provinceantique'))
        })
    )
    list_filter = ('users__nom',)
    search_fields = (
        'id',
        'titre',
        'prov_pays__nom',
        'prov_region__nom',
        'prov_departement__nom',
        'prov_ville__nom', 
        'cons_pays__nom', 
        'cons_region__nom', 
        'cons_departement__nom', 
        'cons_ville__nom', 
        'cons_depot',
        'materiau__nom', 
        'provinceantique__nom', 
        'siteantique__nom', 
        'citeantique__nom'
    )
    autocomplete_fields = ('prov_pays', 'prov_region', 'prov_departement','prov_ville', 'cons_pays', 'cons_region', 'cons_departement', 'cons_ville', 'materiau', 'ensemble', 'provinceantique', 'citeantique', 'monument', 'cons_depot')
    inlines = [OrnementInline, MoulureInline, ComposanteInline, IllusInline]
    pnt = Point(5.855572,47.019214, srid=4326)
    pnt.transform(900913)
    default_lon, default_lat = pnt.coords
    extra = 0
```

Here's what the admin looks like:

[image]

The TinyMCE editor should show up after "Résumé". The dimensions are actually good, according the settings, but the interface doesn't show up. I guess it can't find the static files but can't figure out what's wrong with my paths setup.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? The UI after the resume doesn't look like the default one for the TextField though so I assume it loads other js/css that could be causing the problem.  Also, when you set widget in admin class ` formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE()}
        }`  you should pass widget class `TinyMCE` and not the instance.

Comment: There was an issue with my local js files and the COMPRESSOR setting. Updating the settings and turning the COMPRESSOR to False fixed the issue. Thanks for your suggestion.